AG Grid - 'suppressAndOrCondition' doesn't work
I am trying to use 'suppressAndOrCondition' filter parameter but it looks like it does not work anymore. I don't know if I am going crazy or what but I did not find any mention about deprecating this option, I did not find any mention in code, on github, in docs/api, on SO, anywhere.
I am using floatingFilter and even with this option set to true, after I set the first value, AndOr condition shows up and it is driving me nuts.
I have the latest version 32.0.1 and I guess I just want to know if anybody is experiencing the same issue, if not I will try to make some example repo.

This is because Ag-grid has deprecated the suppressAndOrCondition option.
It shows the below warning message on console on v31:
AG Grid: Since v29.2 "filterParams.suppressAndOrCondition" is deprecated. Use "filterParams.maxNumConditions = 1" instead.
You can learn the usage of the maxNumConditions here
